# C# OCR MODI Example returns an error

Tags: c#, exception, orc

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41709/How-To-Use-Office-2007-OCR-Using-C

I found this example for OCR, pasted some images in C:/ORC folder with black english text on a white background and i still get an exception at this line

MODI.Document md = new MODI.Document();

Saying : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {40942A6C-1520-4132-BDF8-BDC1F71F547B} failed due to the following error: 80040154.
   at OCRSample.Form1.CheckFileType(String directoryPath) in c:\Users\Dmetrey\Desktop\OCRSample\OCRSample\Form1.cs:line 50

Could someone clarify what could be the cause of this exception? I am using VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, changed the platform target to x86 and OCR is now working!